# Check if a String is ALL CAPS in PHP

Tags: php, string

What's the best way to see if a string contains all capital letters? I still want the function to return true if the string also contains symbols or numbers.

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->isUpperCase()`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/ea3e40132e9d4ce27da337dae6286f2478b15f56/src/Str.php#L262) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Comment: See my solution below - no regex or functions required for this.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Check whether `strtoupper($str) == $str`

To handle non-ascii use:

`mb_strtoupper($str, 'utf-8') == $str`

Comment: Simple and sweet! Like the legend that Russians used pencil in space.

Comment: Except it doesnt work for "normal but non english" characters:
 more strtoupper('øæåØÆÅabcABC') > øæåØÆÅABCABC

mb_convert_case or mb_strtoupper

Comment: == didn't work for me
I'd rather use if (strtoupper($string) != $string)

Answer (score 12):

[ctype_upper(string $testString)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-upper.php)

Comment: As this answer is getting attention, it is interesting to note that it does not reply correctly to the question, because it does not consider numbers, as requested by the author.

Comment: Should note that Ctype functions are part of `Variable and Type Related Extensions`. Should also note that builtin support for ctype is available since `PHP 4.3.0`.

Comment: ctype_upper will return false if the string contains a number. See my solution below.

Comment: Unfortunately this incorrect answer has too many upvotes to be deleted.  Sadly, it will continue to confuse and misinform future researchers.   ...if only it could be deleted somehow.

Answer (score 9):

If you want numbers included (and by "symbols" most everything else), then what you are actually trying to test for is the *absence* of lowercase letters:

```
 $all_upper = !preg_match("/[a-z]/", $string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match()`. The regular expression would be `/^[^a-z]+$/`.

```
return preg_match('/^[^a-z]+$/', $string) === 1 ? true : false;
```

Here is the documentation for preg_match().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

PCRE solution:

```
$all_uppercase = preg_match('#^[A-Z]+$#', $string);
```

just make sure you don't use 'i' modifier

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mb_strtoupper($string)===$string)
{
  do the required task
}
else
{
  some other task
}
```

Comment: You have to supply 'utf-8' as a second argument  ie. mb_strtoupper('øæåØÆÅabcABC', 'utf-8');

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this function

```
$myString = "ABCDE";
if (ctype_upper($myString)) // returns true if is fully uppercase
{
    echo "the string $myString is fully uppercase";
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Should note that Ctype functions are part of `Variable and Type Related Extensions`. Should also note that builtin support for ctype is available since `PHP 4.3.0`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I handle ALL CAPS text for my comments section.

```
if ($str == strtoupper($str))
{
    $str = ucfirst(strtolower($str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alexander Morland's comment on Winston Ewert's answer if you need to deal with utf-8 accented characters you can use the following set of functions:

```
define('CHARSET', 'utf-8');

function custom_substr($content='',$pos_start=0,$num_char=1){
    $substr='';
    if(function_exists('mb_substr')){
        $substr=mb_substr($content,$pos_start,$num_char,CHARSET);
    }
    else{
        $substr=substr($content,$pos_start,$num_char);
    }
    return $substr;
}
function custom_str_case($string='', $case='lower'){
    $lower = array(
        "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
        "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "à", "á", "â", "ã", "ä", "å", "æ", "ç", "è", "é", "ê", "ë", "ì", "í", "î", "ï",
        "ð", "ñ", "ò", "ó", "ô", "õ", "ö", "ø", "ù", "ú", "û", "ü", "ý", "а", "б", "в", "г", "д", "е", "ё", "ж",
        "з", "и", "й", "к", "л", "м", "н", "о", "п", "р", "с", "т", "у", "ф", "х", "ц", "ч", "ш", "щ", "ъ", "ы",
        "ь", "э", "ю", "я"
    );
    $upper = array(
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U",
        "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "À", "Á", "Â", "Ã", "Ä", "Å", "Æ", "Ç", "È", "É", "Ê", "Ë", "Ì", "Í", "Î", "Ï",
        "Ð", "Ñ", "Ò", "Ó", "Ô", "Õ", "Ö", "Ø", "Ù", "Ú", "Û", "Ü", "Ý", "А", "Б", "В", "Г", "Д", "Е", "Ё", "Ж",
        "З", "И", "Й", "К", "Л", "М", "Н", "О", "П", "Р", "С", "Т", "У", "Ф", "Х", "Ц", "Ч", "Ш", "Щ", "Ъ", "Ъ",
        "Ь", "Э", "Ю", "Я"
    );

    if($case=='lower'){
        $string = str_replace($upper, $lower, $string);
    }
    else{
        $string = str_replace($lower, $upper, $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
function custom_strtolower($string){
    return custom_str_case($string,'lower');
}
function custom_strtoupper($string){
    return custom_str_case($string,'upper');
}

function custom_ucfirst($string){
    $string=custom_strtolower($string);

    $first_char=custom_substr($string,0,1);
    $rest_char=custom_substr($string,1,custom_strlen($string));
    $first_char=custom_strtoupper($first_char);

    return $first_char.$rest_char;
}

function is_uppercase($string=''){
    $is_uppercase=false;

    if($string === custom_strtoupper($string)) {
       $is_uppercase=true;
    }

    return $is_uppercase;
}
function is_ucfirst($string=''){
    $first_char=custom_substr($string,0,1);

    $is_ucfirst=is_uppercase($first_char);

    return $is_ucfirst;
}
```

Resources:: https://github.com/rafasashi/PHP-Custom-String-Functions